# MariaDB SQL Recursive query as subquery

Tags: recursion, mariadb, subquery, in-subquery, with-clause

I have a data structure where:

- a vendor has a contingent (multiple vendors can use the same contingent, that's why it is different tables)
- A contingent can also have a parent contingent (unlimited in depth)
- If one of the contingents in the chain has nothing left, the vendor is considered to no contingent left
- If the remains are `NULL`, there is no limit set, and it counts as contingent available

*A redesign of the data structure to solve this, sadly, is not possible.*

The recursive part and all contigent-avalible rules cann be coded like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec_contigents as (
  SELECT 
    id, IFNULL(daily_remain, 1) > 0 as row_contigent, parent_id
  FROM contingents
  Where id = 1
  UNION
  select pc.id, IFNULL(pc.daily_remain, 1) > 0 as row_contigent, pc.parent_id
  FROM contingents pc, rec_contigents c
  where pc.id = c.parent_id)
select id, SUM(row_contigent) = count(row_contigent) as contigent from rec_contigents;
```

I can easily get all my vendors, and then query the above for them one by one.
Though, I thought let's reduce Database calls, and use the above as a subquery. *(simplified, in reality this contains multiple JOINS on Vendor and some where-clauses)*

```
SELECT
  v.vendor_id,
  (
        WITH RECURSIVE rec_contigents as (
            SELECT 
            id, IFNULL(daily_remain, 1) > 0 as row_contigent, parent_id
            FROM contingents
            Where id = v.contingent_id
            UNION
            select pc.id, IFNULL(pc.daily_remain, 1) > 0 as row_contigent, pc.parent_id
            FROM contingents pc, rec_contigents c
            where pc.id = c.parent_id
        )
        select SUM(row_contigent) = count(row_contigent) as contigent from rec_contigents
    ) as contingent_left
  FROM vendors AS v
```

This results in the error: `Unknown column 'v.contingent_id' in 'where clause'`.

Following example data:

```
CREATE TABLE `contingents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `daily` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `daily_remain` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

INSERT INTO `contingents` (`id`, `daily`, `daily_remain`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
    (1,10,10,NULL),
    (2,10,5,1),
    (3,10,NULL,2),
    (4,10,0,NULL),
    (5,10,10,4);

CREATE TABLE `vendors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contingent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `vendors` (`id`, `contingent_id`)
VALUES
    (1,3),
    (2,5);
```

Expected outcome:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| vendor_id | contingent_left |
+-----------+-----------------+
|     1     |        1        |
|     2     |        0        |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Vendor 1: Has Contingent, because he and all his parents all have Continent left (or have unlimited contingent).
Vendor 2: Does not have continent, because its parent does not have continent left.

I have already looked at the following posts, though these solutions don't work for me:

- [Mysql Mariadb recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59704314/mysql-mariadb-recursive-query) - uses a JOIN on the recursive table, that I can't use as I first need to sum it
- [SQL Recursive query as subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438992/sql-recursive-query-as-subquery) - says to remove the `Where id = v.contingent_id` which results in to much data and the `select SUM(row_contigent) = count(row_contigent) as contigent from rec_contigents` resulting in the wrong result

Comment: CTE shouldn't be a part of **sub**query - move it to the whole query. And apply `Where id = v.contingent_id` in outer query.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: Explain your desired output in details.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS MySQL<>MariaDB. Which? Also that query is not minimal.

Comment: "`SELECT v.vendor_id, ( ... ) as contingent_left FROM vendors AS v`" There is no vendor_id column in vendors/v. Again: *A [mre] is code you cut & pasted & ran from your post.*

Comment: If you replace v.vendor_id by v.id, your query works in MySQL 8.0 & PostgreSQL 10 but same old problem in MariaDB 10.6. So seems like a bug. PS You have a bunch of contigents that should be contingents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT ven.id,
         CASE WHEN con.daily_remain = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END have_zero,
         con.parent_id
  FROM vendors ven
  JOIN contingents con ON ven.contingent_id = con.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte.id, 
         CASE WHEN con.daily_remain = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         con.parent_id
  FROM cte
  JOIN contingents con ON cte.parent_id = con.id
  WHERE NOT have_zero
)
-- SELECT * FROM cte
SELECT id, NOT MAX(have_zero) contingent_left
FROM cte
GROUP BY id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/wVJDsp4V